# RubyMine Terminal cuts off text

Tags: rubymine

For some reason within RubyMine 6.3.3, in the terminal I'll type a command but the text gets cut off after so many characters.

[image: I type, cursor moves, text disappears]

I'll keep typing, and the cursor will move, but the text is not displayed.

I'm fairly confident that this has something to do with the terminal using good ol' Window's terminal, but I'm so new to RubyMine that I can find no solutions on how to fix this.

Same Problem on Windows 8.1 with RubyMine 7.1.1